# react js : axios fecth data using a get request condition : i want names with those values with taken: true

Tags: reactjs

i am getting a axios get request response like this  in react js

```
0: {id: 60, name: 'hari', taken: false}
1: {id: 64, name: 'kevin', taken: false}
2: {id: 73, name: 'meenu', taken: true}
3: {id: 75, name: 'hari1', taken: false}
4: {id: 69, name: 'kevin2', taken: true}
3: {id: 66, name: 'hari3', taken: false}
4: {id: 68, name: 'kevin4', taken: true}
```

store the  set of values in a state  i want example for both funtional componet and class componet
i want to set those values with `taken: true` in to a state so i can render the names in jsx

Comment: Just to clarify your question, you just want to get all the values that has a taken: true ?

Comment: yes i want the name and id  that has taken as true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const one = [{ id: 60, name: 'hari', taken: false },
{ id: 64, name: 'kevin', taken: false },
{ id: 73, name: 'meenu', taken: true },
{ id: 75, name: 'hari1', taken: false },
{ id: 69, name: 'kevin2', taken: true },
{ id: 66, name: 'hari3', taken: false },
{ id: 68, name: 'kevin4', taken: true }]

const two = [{ id: 73, name: 'meenu', taken: true }, { id: 69, name: 'kevin2', taken: true }]


console.log('one', getTrueData(one))
console.log('two', getTrueData(two))

function getTrueData(data) {
    return data.filter((e) => e.taken === true)
}
```

Comment: 0: {id: 73, name: 'meenu', taken: true}   1: {id: 69, name: 'kevin2', taken: true} i got data like this how to extract names from this

Comment: @MeenuKs I updated my answer so you can now use it as a reusable function